# Understanding c++ function with missing variables in Arduino's RTClib

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to understand a function call that doesn't supply the required parameters but seems to work.  The code is in an Arduino library called RTClib.  Why/how does this work????

The function making the call:

```
uint8_t DateTime::dayOfWeek() const {    
    uint16_t day = date2days(yOff, m, d);
    return (day + 6) % 7; // Jan 1, 2000 is a Saturday, i.e. returns 6
}
```

The function being called:

```
static uint16_t date2days(uint16_t y, uint8_t m, uint8_t d) {
    if (y >= 2000)
        y -= 2000;
    uint16_t days = d;
    for (uint8_t i = 1; i < m; ++i)
        days += pgm_read_byte(daysInMonth + i - 1);
    if (m > 2 && y % 4 == 0)
        ++days;
    return days + 365 * y + (y + 3) / 4 - 1;
}
```

The full library: https://github.com/adafruit/RTClib

Comment: `DateTime::dayOfWeek` is clearly a c++ class and has as expected three instance variables of that name.

Comment: What's wrong with passing the parameters `yOff, m, d`?  If you're wondering where those 3 variables come from, they are members of the `DateTime` class.
If I'm misunderstanding your question let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The required variables are from the DateTime class. They are protected variables, so all methods in the DateTime class can access them.

As seen in [RTClib.h line 27](https://github.com/adafruit/RTClib/blob/master/RTClib.h):

```
protected:
    uint8_t yOff, m, d, hh, mm, ss;
```

Those variables are set by the various [functions in RTClib.cpp](https://github.com/adafruit/RTClib/blob/master/RTClib.cpp), such as the constructors  that first initialize them:

```
DateTime::DateTime (uint16_t year, uint8_t month, uint8_t day, uint8_t hour, uint8_t min, uint8_t sec) {
    if (year >= 2000)
        year -= 2000;
    yOff = year;
    m = month;
    d = day;
    hh = hour;
    mm = min;
    ss = sec;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Pretty obvious now that you point it out.  Would I be correct in assuming the date2days function cannot be used without initializing a DateTime object?

Comment: Correct, the compiler will make it impossible for you to do that.